# GCE refresh private ips dns

Tags: domain-name-system, google-cloud-platform

When starting/stopping servers in GCE, their private IP's are being reused all the time.

When running `host X.X.X.X` with a specific IP that was used before, more than one response is returned, which is causing some issues with a specific system we are using.

Is there some way to tell GCE to "refresh" the list or maybe change the private IP to a brand new one?

Update:
opened a bug at GCE bug tracker:
https://code.google.com/p/google-compute-engine/issues/detail?id=256

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The internal IPs are assigned automatically through Google DHCP. As such, its not possible to assign the IPs manually to the instance.

With that said, depending on how your system is getting the IP information one workaround I can think of is to configure static network IP address to the instance. This can be done with the combination of routes and instnace's --can-ip-forward ability. You can find more information and steps on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances-and-network#staticnetworkaddress)

Other workaround could be reserve [static Public IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances-and-network#reserve_new_static) for your instance.

Comment: I didn't want to manually configure any specific routes, because those servers are going up and down all the time.
I ended using their public IP instead.

Comment: One thing to consider when using the static public IPs for your instance is the quota limit. By default every project has a quota limit of 7 static IPs. However, you can request to increase the limit by filling this quota request form(https://docs.google.com/a/google.com/forms/d/1vb2MkAr9JcHrp6myQ3oTxCyBv2c7Iyc5wqIKqE3K4IE/viewform).